# how to get current rotation of iPad in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an app with Items and Selections. The way it will work as far as GUI there will be a lots of UIImageView's. This looks relatively boring so I decided to make the UIImageView's Move. The way I thought would work best if it would move with the rotation of the device, like the iOS 7 wallpaper and App icons. What I need is some code which will detect the amount of rotation. e.g. if The device was on a 35° Angle the App would output 35. What is the easiest way of doing this? Thanks in Advance, Jayden.

Answer (score 0):

> *I thought would work best if it would move with the rotation of the device, like the iOS 7 wallpaper and App icons.*

If you really want it to behave like the iOS 7 wallpaper and icons, rather than getting the raw accelerometer/gyro data and converting it yourself to an angle of rotation, you can simply use the `UIInterpolatingMotionEffect`. This is a new class in iOS 7 that's specifically designed for you to easily get the kind of accelerometer driven effects you're after.

The documentation [is available here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIInterpolatingMotionEffect_class/Reference/Reference.html), and you simply pick the axis you'd like to measure and the property to map it to (in your case, some kind of transform).